# How can I generate a .war file of my AngularJS project without maven?

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, war

I want to generate my war file of my AngularJS project without maven.

The following is my project structure

[image]

and my **app** folder has the following structure

[image]

Working on **Eclipse** project, however no need to create war using it.

I have installed `grunt, grunt-war` in my machine.

Please find the contect of my `package.json` file

```
{
 "name": "abc",
 "version": "0.0.0",
 "dependencies": {
 },
 "devDependencies": {
   "grunt": "~0.4.1",
   "grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.4.1",
   "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.3.0",
   "grunt-contrib-coffee": "~0.7.0",
   "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.2.0",
   "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.6.0",
   "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "~0.6.0",
   "grunt-contrib-connect": "~0.3.0",
   "grunt-contrib-clean": "~0.4.1",
   "grunt-contrib-htmlmin": "~0.1.3",
   "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "~0.1.4",
   "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.4.0",
   "underscore.string": "~2.3.1",
   "grunt-usemin": "~0.1.11",
   "grunt-rev": "~0.1.0",
   "grunt-karma": "~0.6.2",    
   "grunt-open": "~0.2.0",
   "grunt-concurrent": "~0.3.0",
   "cheerio": "0.12.0",
   "matchdep": "~0.1.2",
   "connect-livereload": "~0.2.0",
   "grunt-ngmin": "~0.0.2",
   "mustache": "~0.7.2",
   "grunt-mcompile": "~0.1.2",
   "grunt-contrib-less": "~0.10.0",
   "expect.js": "*",
   "CSSselect": "0.3.1",
   "CSSwhat": "0.2.0", 
   "karma": "0.10.9",
   "karma-chrome-launcher": "~0.1",
   "karma-coffee-preprocessor": "~0.1",
   "karma-firefox-launcher": "~0.1",        
   "karma-jasmine": "~0.1",
   "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "~0.1",
    "karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor":"~0.1",
    "grunt-angular-templates": "~0.5.3"
   },
   "engines": {
   "node": ">=0.8.0"
   }
  }
```

But I don't know how to write `gruntfile.js` to build the war file of the above application structure.

I tried with the `grunt-war`[click here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-war)

By following this I can create **.war** but it contains only **web.xml**

So help me to get this done....